# How easy is Drupal for E-Commerce?

Tags: users, database

I'm looking for the right tool to develop a peer to peer trading website that would include E-Commerce. The site would need to allow registered sellers to enter details about their products this information would then need to be stored in a database that would allow buyers to search based on a set of parameters.

Would all this be achievable with current Drupal modules and how much additional coding would be required to knit it all together?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any coding to achieve this functionality, you can just go with [Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) and using Drupal's built-in roles, manage who has the permission to create content (items to sell) and who has the permission to buy it.

for the search aspect of it, I suggest trying [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), which gives you facet like filtering feature (Like ebay), also you might wanna check [Apache Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) for faster indexing

Comment: Thanks guys. Really useful I'll check out the suggested links and give it a go. When is D8 due for release?

Answer (score 1):

> Would all this be achievable with current Drupal modules

Yes your requirements/specs seem to be perfectly doable with "current" Drupal, if you're talking about Drupal version 7 and starting from [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) with specific add-on modules.

For Drupal version 8, things will get even better ... provided you can be a bit patient. Refer to [Commerce 2.x for Drupal 8](https://modulesunraveled.com/podcast/154-commerce-2x-drupal-8-bojan-zivanovic-modules-unraveled-podcast) for lots of details about what's coming up in D8 ...

> How much additional coding would be required to knit it all together?

Since Drupal Commerce is pretty much entity based, you'll get a lot of things done without additional coding, only using modules such as [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group), etc.